# How to improve Firefox performance?

Tags: performance, firefox, memory, ram

I usually use Firefox as my main web browser, but one of the major problems it has is its memory consumption. After an hour using it, and with no more than 20 tabs opened, it can consume more than 1 GB, and this memory isn't released even if I close the majority or the tabs I have opened. The only solution in this situation is restarting it.

I have read some articles about tuning Firefox, such as:

- http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=53650
- http://sswam.com/2011/05/19/tuning-firefox-for-speed-enable-http-pipelining-etc/
- http://www.technical-assistance.co.uk/kb/ffconfig.php

But the solutions given in these articles didn't work for me.

Has anyone managed to tun it to not consume an excesive amount of memory?
Thank you in advance

Comment: try this: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-uses-too-much-memory-ram I do use Firefox and it does use a lot of RAM, I have 20-40 tabs open (using groups a lot of the time).  I also have a number of addons...it rarely uses 1GB - usually hovering around 700-800MB at worst (400MB just now).  I would also make sure it is the latest version

Comment: I'm afraid these recommendations didn't help me :(

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issues. After some digging, I've found this out:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-slow-how-make-it-faster

It was very usefull to me. Hope it could help you too.

**EDIT**: The original link I've posted is offline. I dig again and decided to refer to this Mozilla's tutorial because it covers most of the hints I used to improve FF.

Comment: Unfortunately the link you provided is no longer valid: "Page Not Found"

Comment: Thanks, @ToniSM! I'd updated the link for another one useful too.

Answer (score 0):

How many extensions/addons are you running? A large part of your problem could be that. Also, if that does indeed turn out to be your issue, a lot of the memory those addons take is tab-independent. So you're right to assume that the only way to stop that is to restart it fully. I use Chrome, so I'm not super familiar with whether or not you can disable extensions/addons individually without shutting your browser down, but I'd look into the possibility of that.